# Travis URL environment variable not working

Tags: mongodb, travis-ci, cicd

I have setup an environment variable named `MONGO_DB_URL` in `Travis` from `GitHub` UI. This variable refers to my `MongoDb` connection string.

When the build runs, this variables returns an empty value. All other variables work, but only the connection URL variables return empty values.

Is there a specific format to be followed? Since I added the value through UI, I did not enclose the string in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. `Travis` reads the `MongoDb` connection string correctly only if it is enclosed within double quotes.